# Qt 5.7 QFileDialog action doesn't work

Tags: macos, qt, shortcut, qfiledialog, qaction

I got filedialog called inside my main window with this code:

```
QAction *actionWithShortcut = new QAction();
actionWithShortcut->setShortcut(Qt::CTRL + Qt::Key_9);
actionWithShortcut->setShortcutContext(Qt::ShortcutContext::WidgetWithChildrenShortcut);
// added this comment to check does it work at list outside filedialog
// addAction(actionWithShortcut);
QFileDialog *fd = new QFileDialog(this);
fd->addAction(actionWithShortcut);
connect(actionWithShortcut, &QAction::triggered, fd, &QFileDialog::reject);
fd->show();
```

But looks like I can't add any actions to `QFileDialog` or they are somehow omitted. Any suggestions? 
Already tried window flags, options and etc. Can't find any solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, a `QFileDialog` is a thin wrapper around the native dialog. Qt didn't go to the lengths needed to wrap actions around the native dialog. So this is a case of a missing implementation. You could patch Qt to make it work on a platform of your choice, and contribute the change back, of course.

The action would presumably work if you were to switch to a non-native file dialog.